# How do I force to change the button text to bold before removing the said button after an alert on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I get a correct sequence in IE, but not in Chrome.
In Chrome the button text was not bold, instead only the alert message and the button is removed.

I tried running developer mode in Chrome and step by step, but the text is showing bold correctly before the alert then removing the button.

Below is my jQuery for the button click.

```
    $("button").click(function() {
      $(this).css('font-weight', '700');
      var elmId = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(elmId);
      $(this).remove();
    });
```

I want to the button text to be bold before the alert message and before removing the said button.

Edit: Solved by answer below

Comment: DOM manipulation and alert runs on main thread it doesn't get time to render in ui since right after it you have alert and then remove. With setTimeout you can give enough time for ui rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not working, because `alert()` executes asynchronously, and that is why, the button gets removed, and changes aren't visible. That is why I have used setTimeout, which starts executing after a certain amount of time. It waits for 1 millisecond, and then generates alert, and removes `button` element. Till then, the CSS changes have taken place, and are visible. :)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  let el = $(this);
  el.css('font-weight', '700');
  var elmId = el.attr("id");
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert(elmId);
    el.remove();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>BOLD</button>
```

Comment: why is his code not working though ? as far as I can see it should be working.

Comment: @Noob I have added the explanation.

Comment: This works now in chrome but not in IE. I also forgot to mention to be atleast cross browser compatibility.

Comment: I never thought that alert executes asynchronously... hmm.

Comment: @PranavRustagi it works in both. But somehow, the button does not get removed.

Comment: @Guine024 check again. Actually I made a minor mistake.

Comment: @PranavRustagi wow it works! Can you tell me what difference did assigning $(this) to a variable?

Comment: Actually, I had to do that because inside `setTimeout`, `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: I see. Thank you @PranavRustagi. Have a great day!